# How do you create SSL socket factory in new Apache Http Client 4.3?

Tags: ssl, apache-commons-httpclient

How do you create SSL socket factory in new Apache Http Client 4.3 ?

Here is how I was creating it before 4.3

```
val ts = new TrustStrategy() {
  def isTrusted(chain: Array[X509Certificate], authType: String): Boolean = true
}

new SSLSocketFactory(ts, SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER)
```

Now `SSLSocketFactory` marked as deprecated. What is the new way of defining custom `TrustStrategy` ? I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I figured it out.

Initialize your `ConnectionSocketFactory` like this

```
val sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy).useTLS().build()
new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, new AllowAllHostnameVerifier())
```

If you take a look at sources of `TrustSelfSignedStrategy` the way they distinguish self-signed certificates from real ones is by checking length of chain.

```
public boolean isTrusted(
        final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType) throws CertificateException {
    return chain.length == 1;
}
```

I'm not sure it's very reliable way but just keep it in mind. Maybe it's worth checking given `X509Certificate` in `isTrusted`.

Comment: What does exactly mean this null value? "SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, ..." Regards

Comment: @Zilevav it's instance of object with key-store (java.security.KeyStore).