# HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory() method not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl-certificate, httpclient, apache-httpclient-5.x

I have used

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents.client5', name: 'httpclient5', version: '5.2'
```

setSSLSocketFactory() method doesn't exist for this dependency

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you create SSL socket factory in new Apache Http Client 4.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061931/how-do-you-create-ssl-socket-factory-in-new-apache-http-client-4-3)

Comment: I have got the same issue, spent the afternoon on that already, did not find any meaningful answer...

Are you pulling from Maven?

Comment: @KhalilBouzekri

`SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory =
                new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContextBuilder.build(),
                        new String[] {"TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"}, null,
                        new NoopHostnameVerifier());


        HttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory).build();

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(connectionManager).build();`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems that the SSLSocketFactory should now be set on the [ConnectionManagerBuilder](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.3.x/current/httpclient5/apidocs/)

See the official documentation here with an example: [Migration to Apache HttpClient 5.x classic APIs](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.3.x/migration-guide/index.html)

Sample code:

```java
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
      .setSSLSocketFactory(SSLConnectionSocketFactoryBuilder.create()
              .setSslContext(SSLContexts.createSystemDefault())
              .setTlsVersions(TLS.V_1_3)
              .build())
      .setDefaultSocketConfig(SocketConfig.custom()
              .setSoTimeout(Timeout.ofMinutes(1))
              .build())
      .setPoolConcurrencyPolicy(PoolConcurrencyPolicy.STRICT)
      .setConnPoolPolicy(PoolReusePolicy.LIFO)
      .setDefaultConnectionConfig(ConnectionConfig.custom()
              .setSocketTimeout(Timeout.ofMinutes(1))
              .setConnectTimeout(Timeout.ofMinutes(1))
              .setTimeToLive(TimeValue.ofMinutes(10))
              .build())
      .build();
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder
                        .create()
                        .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                        .build();
```

I did it and it is working fine

Answer (score 15):

Taking the answer from @Ayshan's comment:

```
    SSLContext sslContext = sslContextBuilder.build();

    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509", "SunJSSE");
    keyManagerFactory.init(clientStore, "".toCharArray());
    sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, new java.security.SecureRandom());

    SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

    HttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create().setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory).build();
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(connectionManager).build();
```

Make sure all the http components are imported from http client 5.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a to use a custom trustStore for the SSL certificate below worked for me.

```
val sslContextBuilder: SSLContextBuilder = SSLContextBuilder.create()

sslContextBuilder.loadTrustMaterial(File("path/to/trustStore"), "trustStorePassword".toCharArray())

val sslContext: SSLContext = sslContextBuilder.build()

val socketFactory = SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext)

val connectionManager: HttpClientConnectionManager = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create().setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory).build()

return HttpClients.custom()
      .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider) // I am using NTLM credentials to connect to SSRS server
      .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
      .setDefaultAuthSchemeRegistry(authSchemaRegistry)
      .build()
```

Ref: https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/5.3.x/httpclient5/src/test/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/examples/ClientCustomSSL.java